# "Bitwise Not" in Python disconsidering 2's complement

Tags: python, binary, twos-complement

I need to do a "~" operation in Python but not taking account of 2's complement. I managed to do that by using **XOR**, do you know another way to do this? (more efficient)

```
a = 0b101
b = 0b10101

print bin(a ^ (2 ** a.bit_length() - 1)) #0b10
print bin(b ^ (2 ** b.bit_length() - 1)) #0b1010
```

Comment: May I ask why? It's possible the `bin` representation is confusing you. `~` does invert the bits; it just inverts an *infinite number* of bits, making it impossible to represent textually. `bin` thus does some messing around with `-` to make it work, but it ends up hiding the fact all the bits are inversed.

Comment: @Veedrac I'm implementing a 16bit vm.

Comment: I think your ways good enough, don't think python has a native way of doing this. A minor change can be using bitshift instead of powers.

Comment: If It's a virtual machine, you probably know the register width, so you can clean it up a touch by hardcoding the expression as `a ^ 0xFFFF`.

Comment: `(1 << b.bit_length() - 1)` is going to be faster than `(2 ** b.bit_length() - 1)` - and yes, hardcode a mask if you can instead of calling `bit_length`.

Comment: @roippi I tried to do `print bin(1 << b.bit_length() - 1)` but it ouputs `0b10000`

Comment: I missed some parentheses, should be `((1 << b.bit_length()) - 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `~` does already. The tricky part is that Python has unlimited length integers, so when you invert a number it is sign extended with--at least conceptually speaking--an infinite number of 1's. Meaning you get negative numbers.

```
>>> bin(~0b101)
'-0b110'
>>> bin(~0b10101)
'-0b10110'
```

To convert these to unsigned numbers, you need to decide how many bits you care about. Maybe you are working with 8-bit bytes. Then you could AND them with a byte's worth of 1 bits:

```
>>> bin(~0b101 & 0xFF)
'0b11111010'
>>> bin(~0b10101 & 0xFF)
'0b11101010'
```

Or if you want to match the exact bit length of the input numbers, your solution is reasonable. For efficiency you could switch the exponent for a left shift. And it might be clearer to use `~` and `&` instead of `^`.

```
>>> bin(~a & ((1 << a.bit_length()) - 1))
'0b10'
>>> bin(~b & ((1 << b.bit_length()) - 1))
'0b1010'
```

(I suspect a hardcoded mask like `& 0xFFFF` will be the right solution in practice. I can't think of a good real world use case for the `bit_length()`-based answer.)

Comment: Thanks, do you know if bit_length uses math or string manipulation?

Comment: `bit_length` doesn't touch strings.

Comment: `bit_length` on CPython is approximately constant time and seems to be blazingly fast so I assume it's just returns an internal cached value.

Comment: You were right a simple `~b & 0xFFFF` solved  https://github.com/leandromoreira/python_chip16/commit/319063e771d162ae53cc962a76f6a6ae60037f05

Answer (score 1):

Another way, though some (including myself) may dispute it's any better, is:

```
tbl = str.maketrans("01","10")

int(bin(42)[2:].translate(tbl),2)
```

The first bit just sets up a translation table to invert `1` and `0` bits in a string.

The second bit gets the binary representation (`42` -> `0b101010`), strips off the `0b` at the front, and inverts the bits through translation. Then you just use `int(,2)` to turn that binary string back into a number.

---

If you can limit it to a specific width rather than using the width of the number itself, then it's a simple matter of (using the example of 32 bits):

```
val = val ^ 0xffff
```